# How to pass arguments to Unit test

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, argparse

I am trying to write an unit test for a function that deals with the argparsers from the users.

My function:

```
def __init_parser() -> argparse.Namespace:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Parsing arguments...',
    )

    parser.add_argument('--task_id', '-t', dest='task_id', action="store", type=str, required=True)

    return parser.parse_args()
```

Test

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('task_id', ('--task_id', '-t'))
def test__init_parser_with_job_id(capsys, task_id):

    args = __init_parser()
```

The error `_jb_pytest_runner.py: error: the following arguments are required: --task_id/-t`

How can I achieve this passing the number of task_id in the body of the test function?

Comment: Problem is that unittest also looks at sys.argv.

Comment: you are correct, I replied my question mocking the sys.argv

Answer (score 1):

As the comment of @hpaulj, the function looks for the argv, so in this case it is necessary to mock it and then proceed with the asserts.

```
def test__init_parser(monkeypatch):
    task_id = '258'

    with mock.patch.object(sys, 'argv', ['startup.py', '--task_id', '258'):
        args = __init_parser()
        job_id = getattr(args, 'task_id')
        assert task_id == '258'
```